# How to get number of author, align author command?

Tags: author-number

I am a new bee in latex. I was building a document that uses ACM SIG Proceedings Templates.
The sample tex file contains \numberofauthors \alignauthor and several other tags. When I try to build it in texstudio, it gives me error complaining unrecognized command like numberofauthors, alignauthor  etc. I have included authblock packages. What other package I have to include to get those tags?

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\begin{document}

\title{Hello World}

\numberofauthors{8}
\author{
% 1st. author
\alignauthor
Ben Trovato\titlenote{Dr.~Trovato insisted his name be first.}\\
       \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
       \affaddr{1932 Wallamaloo Lane}\\
       \affaddr{Wallamaloo, New Zealand}\\
       \email{trovato@corporation.com}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor
G.K.M. Tobin\titlenote{The secretary disavows
any knowledge of this author's actions.}\\
       \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
       \affaddr{P.O. Box 1212}\\
       \affaddr{Dublin, Ohio 43017-6221}\\
       \email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
% 3rd. author
\alignauthor Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld\titlenote{This author is the
one who did all the really hard work.}\\
       \affaddr{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}\\
       \affaddr{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}\\
       \affaddr{Hekla, Iceland}\\
       \email{larst@affiliation.org}
\and  % use '\and' if you need 'another row' of author names
% 4th. author
\alignauthor Lawrence P. Leipuner\\
       \affaddr{Brookhaven Laboratories}\\
       \affaddr{Brookhaven National Lab}\\
       \affaddr{P.O. Box 5000}\\
       \email{lleipuner@researchlabs.org}
% 5th. author
\alignauthor Sean Fogarty\\
       \affaddr{NASA Ames Research Center}\\
       \affaddr{Moffett Field}\\
       \affaddr{California 94035}\\
       \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
% 6th. author
\alignauthor Charles Palmer\\
       \affaddr{Palmer Research Laboratories}\\
       \affaddr{8600 Datapoint Drive}\\
       \affaddr{San Antonio, Texas 78229}\\
       \email{cpalmer@prl.com}
}
\additionalauthors{Additional authors: John Smith (The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group,
email: {\texttt{jsmith@affiliation.org}}) and Julius P.~Kumquat
(The Kumquat Consortium, email: {\texttt{jpkumquat@consortium.net}}).}
\date{30 July 1999}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Provide us with some code that replicates your problem. However simple or straight-forward this may sound, it would greatly help us to help you. We call this a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I have updated the question with codes. My texstudio is compaining that alignauthor , numberofauthor,affaddr are unrecognized command.

Comment: I can compile it without problem on my machine. Perhaps, when you compile, add `\listfiles` to your preamble (in an attempt to see [which package version you are using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X)) and paste the `.log` file as part of your original post. You may have an [outdated distribution that requires updating](http://goo.gl/CqWB1).

Comment: Do you have the .cls (something like sig-alternate-05-2015.cls) file in the same folder?